# In Assassin’s Creed how can Eagle Vision be passed through the family?

Tags: genetics, assassins-creed

How can the Assassin’s Creed sense, Eagle Vision be given to an Assassin’s child in Assassin’s Creed when the majority of Assassins in Assassin’s Creed are male and the females that the Assassin males who have the Super Assassin sense proceate with the females who seemingly don't have the gift of "Eagle Vision".

e.g. Edward Kenway marries and has sex with his wife who doesn't have Eagle Vision to see the world in almost negative.

Haytham, Edwards son has Eagle Vision and has sex with his wife who doesn't have the super sense to see the world in almost negative.

Then Connor Kenway is made and has the sense.

How can this happen wouldn't as the gift becomes "tainted" by non Eagle Vision carriers this ability dwindle and fade?

Like a quarter Eagle Vision? Or a half Eagle Vision or something?

Comment: I basically want to know how can Eagle Vision be passed down the family when usually the female giving birth to the baby doesn't have eagle vision? And would it fade away as it travels down the family tree, kind of like how wizard blood is in harry potter

Comment: Magic attribute gets passed down magically?

Comment: It’s a magic power in a universe of special magic powers. I doubt there’s much more to it than that.

Comment: @DavidW the pure bloods would think so

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I get what your saying because "video game logic" but considering they "try" to make Assassins Creed seem real it seems like the creators overlooked a really important main part of the game

Comment: If it’s a dominant gene then nothing is overlooked.

Comment: But if it's recessive, that would answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a single gene, then it cannot be tainted or watered down. Everyone has zero, one or two copies of the gene.

If it's a "dominant" gene then one copy is enough to get the full effect.

If Alice doesn't have it, and Bob has one copy, each of their children will either have one copy or zero, at random.

If their children and grandchildren breed with people who don't have it, roughly a quarter of their grandchildren will have it, and about an eighth of their great grand children, and so on.

Those grandchildren all either have one just like Bob or zero just like Alice. There's no in-between.

The ones who have zero are irrelevant to the plot, so it doesn't matter how many of them there are. All that matters to the plot is that at least one descendant still has it.

Answer (score 0):

Eagle Vision is caused by Isu DNA, so those with a higher concentration of it will sometimes inherently know how to use this skill (or at least have an easier time 'unlocking' their own potential for it).
As far as I recall, Ubisoft didn't specify that it requires one specific gene, so the dominant and recessive theory isn't strictly accurate, but that detail doesn't make much difference here.
Since humans were created by the Isu, everyone has some small amount of Isu DNA and in theory everyone in the AC universe would be capable of honing their skills and developing eagle vision.

In Black Flag Edward says he's been able to see the world through his Eagle Vision lens since childhood, and we already know that Desmond has a high concentration of Isu DNA, so it's safe to assume that since they're related, Edward does too.
This would explain how Haytham and Connor both find that Eagle Vision comes naturally to them.